# File not found (cygwin on Windows)

Tags: shell-script, cygwin

- Windows 7
- TeX Live 2014

I am trying to install [Minion Pro and Myriad Pro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/) for the use with pdflatex. When I try to run the script in `cygwin` via

```
name@pc-name /cygdrive/d/LaTeX/FontPro-master-Build01
$ ./scripts/makeall MinionPro --expanded
```

...this is what happens:

```
Chosen font family is MinionPro
Different font versions found: --pack option is disabled
Creating PostScript fonts ...
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: glyph ‘sterling.oldstyle’: Whilng otf/MinionPro-Bold.otf:
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: glyph ‘sterling.oldstyle’: warnex flex hint replaced with curves
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: (This Type 2 format font containts prohibited by Type 1.
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: I’ve safely replaced them with urves.)
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: glyph ‘colonmonetary.oldstyle’:cessing otf/MinionPro-It.otf:
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: glyph ‘colonmonetary.oldstyle’:complex flex hint replaced with curves
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: (This Type 2 format font containts prohibited by Type 1.
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: I’ve safely replaced them with urves.)
Creating TeX metrics ...
./scripts/makeall: Zeile 93: perl: Kommando nicht gefunden.
 < 62) : Syntaxfehler: Ungültiger arithmetischer Operator. (Fehlerveru < 62) \").t \"
scripts/maketfm: Zeile 245: bc: Kommando nicht gefunden.
```

(I cut many lines similar to the last one with "Kommando nicht gefunden". Had to hit `Ctrl + C` to stop it.)

So apparently the file `maketfm` in the same isn't found due to the typical difference in the slashes. Does anyone have any idea how I can remedy this?

### New version, after installing perl for cygwin

```
$ ./scripts/makeall MinionPro --expanded
Chosen font family is MinionPro
Different font versions found: --pack option is disabled
Creating PostScript fonts ...
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: glyph ‘sterling.oldstyle’: While processing otf/MinionPro-Bold.otf:
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: glyph ‘sterling.oldstyle’: warning: complex flex hint replaced with curves
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: (This Type 2 format font contains flex hints prohibited by Type 1.
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: I’ve safely replaced them with ordinary curves.)
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: glyph ‘colonmonetary.oldstyle’: While processing otf/MinionPro-It.otf:
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: glyph ‘colonmonetary.oldstyle’: warning: complex flex hint replaced with curves
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: (This Type 2 format font contains flex hints prohibited by Type 1.
C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\cfftot1.exe: I’ve safely replaced them with ordinary curves.)
Creating TeX metrics ...
 < 62) : Syntaxfehler: Ungültiger arithmetischer Operator. (Fehlerverursachendes < 62) \").t \"
```

Comment: Isn't it the `perl` and `bc` commands that are not found? Does your cygwin system have those installed?

Comment: @steeldriver Could very well be. ... I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: @steeldriver Well that was stupid. Yes, the missing `perl` library was the first error. Anyhow, now it stops at the arithmetic operator error. (see updated OP)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the files you downloaded have Windows [line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations). But Cygwin bash requires Unix line endings. Unix lines end with a line feed (LF) character while Windows lines end with the two-character combination carriage return, line feed (CR LF). As far as bash is concerned, there are CR characters at the end of each line, and they're causing a syntax error.

Convert at least the shell scripts to Unix line endings:

```
dos2unix scripts/*
unix2dos scripts/*.bat
```